Get rid of the vibrancy effect put behind List headers given the .plain style on iPad
I am using a List for a heavily customized interface. This is mostly because of the header field and how in the .plain mode headers are sticky above the content.
The problem is that the headers seem to get a vibrancy effect. This is undesirable because in this case the header is only supposed to be a single button on the left.
Is there any way to get rid of this vibrancy effect? Or should I be building my own sticky header implementation with some complicated geometry reader logic?


How about a LazyVStack in a ScrollView instead?

That's what I may need to go to but I would not get the floating header effect without a bunch of effort.... or at least that is my understanding.

You can easily get a floating header in a LazyVStack. Check out the pinnedViews parameter of its initializer.

YES! Do you wanna post that as an answer. Easy accept. I found another answer (and I will post it) but that ones better.

Since the UI you want looks nothing like a built-in List, I'd suggest just build it using a LazyVStack in a ScrollView. You can use pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders to get sticky section headers like in a .plain list.
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack(pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
        Section("Header 1") {
            ...
        }
        Section("Header 2") {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}


Another solution I found is to give the header a frame of 0 and have the UI in an overlay like so
Section {
    Text("Section \(num)")
        .padding(.leading, 100)
} header: {
    VStack {}
        .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Text("Header")
                .padding()
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).fill(.white))
                .frame(width: 120, height: 20)
        }
}

